# GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity not getting the latest AD group

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

The issue I am having is that the newly added AD groups don't seem to be immediately searchable via `GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity()` method.

Below is the code I used for adding the group.

```
// to add a new AD group
using (var group = new GroupPrincipal(context, groupName))
{
   group.GroupScope = GroupScope.Universal;
   group.Save();
}
```

One thing I'd like to mention here is that the PrincipalContext object `context` is only created once at the constructor of my AD service class, and I am reusing the same `context` object throughout the life of the service class. Not sure if this would cause any potential issues here.

So what can I do to get the most up-to-date AD groups right after the new groups are added?

Answer (score 1):

I could achive this by adding a CommitChanges on the underlying directory entry.

```
public static void Test()
{
    var context = PrincipalContextProvider.ProvideContext();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        using (var group = new GroupPrincipal(context, $"Hello_World_{i}"))
        {
            group.GroupScope = GroupScope.Universal;
            group.Save();
            ((DirectoryEntry)group.GetUnderlyingObject()).CommitChanges();
        }

        var _group = GetGroup($"CN=Hello_World_{i},CN=Users,DC=abc,DC=com");
        Console.WriteLine(_group.Name);
    }
}
```

For explanation: The PrincipalContextProvider simply provides a context as you use in your code. The CommitChanges method, saves changes that are made to a directory entry to the underlying directory store. You also need the Save method! And at least, the GetGroups methods queries the group by its LDAP Path (its uses a new principal context and i'm not sure if it makes any differents). Hope it helps to go forward.